# Using SQLite database in RESTful API

Tags: rest, sqlite

recently i've been given task to write a simple RESTful API using SQLite DB backend, locally. It's my first time coding web API and I have one main problem. I don't know how can I access my database using HTML requests (in REST API). So far I've created simple RESTful API, something like in this video :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JeIE3jzAxHU

And I've created my SQLite DB using this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=alDxmm7iAB4

But I have no idea how to connect those two. I would highly appreciate any help or some sites where I can learn how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You posted two videos for .net and asp so, you must use something like that [Create a web API with ASP.NET Core and Visual Studio for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api)

From my point of view, you must start from understand what is RESTful and after, start to implement your code.
I suggest you to lock some other code like this [Create Simple RESTAPI In Php](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2017/02/create-simple-rest-api-in-php.html) because .net it's fantastic tool and make a lot of things for you but, at the beginning you can lose the control of your app.

Comment: Thanks for answer, unfortunately not all my problems were solved after reading these links. I still dont know how to create my SQLite DB on localhost and how to operate on it through my HTTP requests. Any hints?

Comment: OK, you have two strategy, manually crate the DB and connect with ADO.NET or use Code first [http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/what-is-code-first.aspx]. For a small project i suggest you to use the first. Remember: SQLite is not a server side DB but client side [https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html], it's more common MySql or MS Sql as DB on server side. You need a web server (usually IIS) to run the web server but it's expensive when you buy a hosting instead of PHP and linux.